# Boolean value from datetime field

Tags: mysql

I need a boolean value (`is_published`) that is indicates if the datetime field `published` is set or is null.

Working example:

```
SELECT published, published IS NOT NULL as is_published  FROM `table`
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking...

Comment: This question does not indicate what the problem is. What did you try, and what issues did you run into? Can you give examples of your attempts and how their results differ from the behaviour that you expect?

Comment: Edited the question to make it easier to understand. If I understood incorrectly, feel free to rollback.

Comment: I edited with the answer from help of theChrisKent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT (CASE publishedDateTime IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END CASE) AS is_published
```